# Meaning of $\log^{O(1)}(a+b)$

Tags: notation

What's the meaning of $\log^{O(1)}(a+b)$ ? Is it simply $(\log_2(a+b))^k$ where k is calculated in constant time ? That is the base 2 logarithm usually in computer science when no other base is set, and the $O(1)$ at the log word means that the whole expression should be raised to the power of that number (which I named k) ?

Comment: You are right about the notation. See here please: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150546/356329

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition
$$O(g)=\{f\colon \exists C>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n> N, f(n)\leqslant C g(n)\}$$
so $O(1)$ can be viewed as set of bounded functions. Outgoing from here $\log^{O(1)}(a+b)$ we can understand as set of functions $\log^{f(n)}(a+b)$ where $f(n) \in O(1)$.

**Addition.**

Understanding of $f \in \log^{O(1)}(a+b)$ not seems to be differ from understanding of $f \in O(1)$ and does not mean that "O(1) can be arbitrary large constant", as is in your comments. $O(1)$ is not constant, or set of constants, but set of functions. In same way $f \in O(1)$ does not mean that $f$ is bounded by any arbitrary large constant, but there $\exists C_f>0$ for which we have $f(n) \leqslant C_f$. So, $f \in \log^{O(1)}(a+b)$, mean, that $\exists g \in O(1)$, i.e. $\exists C_g>0$ $g(n) \leqslant C_g$, such that $f(n)=\log^{g(n)}(a+b)$. In words: function $f$ is bounded by $\log$ having bounded function in superscript. For example, $f$ cannot be $\log^n(a+b)$, but can be $\log^{\frac{1}{n}}(a+b)$ or $\log^{\frac{1}{n}+1}(a+b)$.

Comment: Thanks but the part of my question is how to understand the superscript if, for example, $log^x(y)=(log(y))^x$ being a way of writing the power of x or if I misunderstood?

Comment: I don't understand at all how the expression $log^{O(1)}(a+b)$ can have an upper bound, because O(1) can be arbitrary large constant iiuc

Comment: @Niklas R. In understanding of superscript I have same view as you and it is in my answer. For second comment I wrote addition.

Comment: Your addition was exactly what I needed. My mistake was yesterday thinking that the expression $log^a(a+b)$ would fulfil the condition of $log^{O(1)}(a+b)$ but f(a) = a is O(a) which grows faster than O(1), which I understood from your final words in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, $\log^{O(1)}(a+b)$ can be rewritten as  $(\log_2(a+b))^{O(1)}$ and $O(1)$ means the power of the $\log$ is less equal than a constant.

If this term is mentioned as an upper bound for a given function $T(n)$, we will know $T(n) = o(n)$ (little-oh). And even more, we can say $T(n)$ is less than any $n^\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A quantity bounded from above by $(\log(a+b))^C$ for some $C > 0$.